# Recyclerview null when trying to get by ID

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I am new to Android dev and I have hit a bump...
I am trying to get a reference to a recyclerview in my activity class and it returns null for some reason? I am calling findViewById function in onCreate. I have read in some places that this is to early to call as the recyclerview has not been created yet, and I should use onCreated. However when I use the onCreated function I get an error stating that it is not overriding anything.

I am  using Kotlin, so I have tried both with and without the null operator (?)
however I still get the same error? Is there any way around this? I am using min SDK version 21, and target ADK version 27 (not sure if that is needed?)

Thanks for your time!

**Activity class**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_list)

    Application.component.inject(this)
    viewModel = itemListViewModel(this, authService, itemService)
    var response = viewModel.getItemsList()

    itemList = response?.itemList!!

    setupRecyclerView()
}

fun setupRecyclerView(){

    var recyclerview = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.item_list)
    var recyclerAdaptor = VenueListAdaptor(this, itemList)
    recyclerview.adapter = recyclerAdaptor

    var verticalManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    verticalManager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
    recyclerview.layoutManager = verticalManager

    recyclerview.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
}
```

** XML Layout**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/item_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

** Adaptor class**

```
class ItemListAdaptor (context: Context, itemList: ArrayList<Item>) :     RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemListAdaptor.ItemListViewHolder>() {

val itemList = itemList
val layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(context)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int):     ItemListViewHolder {
    val view = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false)
    val viewholder = ItemListViewHolder(view)
    return viewholder
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
   return itemList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: itemListViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val data = itemList.get(position)
    holder.setData(data, position)
}

class ItemListViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
{
    lateinit var itemName: TextView
    lateinit var item: Item

    init{
        if(itemView != null){
            // find item and set data here
        }
    }

    fun setData(item: Item, position : Int){
        //set item data here
    }
}
```

}

Comment: could you post some code?

Comment: I have added some code snippets, thanks

Comment: Please post your error log

Comment: The only error I get is on this line recyclerview.adapter = recyclerAdaptor. The error I get is recyclerview = null

Comment: Where is your VenueListAdaptor? I can only see an ItemListAdaptor.

Answer (score 0):

Call `setupRecyclerView` method just after `setContentView`

Comment: Thanks for reply, unfortunately it is still returning null